SvelteKit Redirect 308 when trying to access internal API from +page.server.ts
I am trying to retrieve data from a local API endpoint route within my SvelteKit application. I can confirm the endpoint works by navigating directly to it at http://localhost:5173/api/getSummary?summaryId=20 where I can see the JSON data as expected.
In a separate route - /(authenticated)/importSummary/+page.svelte - I import a component in the same directory that utilizes this API endpoint:
<script lang="ts">
    export async function showInfo() {
        const createSummary_response = await fetch("/api/getSummary/?summaryId=20", {
            method: "GET",
        });

        const createSummary_response_data = await createSummary_response.json();
        console.log("createSummary_response_data:", createSummary_response_data);
    }
</script>

This works as expected and I receive the data. My problem is when I try to access this same endpoint from a +page.server.ts, in this case at /(authenticated)/manageSummary/+page.server.ts:
import type { PageServerLoad } from './$types'

export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({ fetch, params }) => {
    const getSummary_response = await fetch(`/api/getSummary/?summaryId=20`, {
        method: "GET",
    });

    const getSummary_response_data = getSummary_response;
    console.log("getSummary_response_data:", getSummary_response_data);
}

to which I receive the following response:
getSummary_response_data: Response {
  status: 308,
  statusText: '',
  headers: Headers { 'x-sveltekit-normalize': '1', location: '/api/getSummary?summaryId=20' },
  body: null,
  bodyUsed: false,
  ok: false,
  redirected: false,
  type: 'default',
  url: ''
}

Logging in my /api/getSummary/+server.ts file suggests that this endpoint is not being reached at all when fetched from the +page.server.ts.

Does using /api/getSummary?summaryId=20 instead of /api/getSummary/?summaryId=20 work? Note that I removed a / after getSummary.

The redirect happens for normalization (changing the URL as suggested should prevent this). What I find odd is that the redirect is not followed so you get the actual response from the API; by default that should be the case with fetch unless the redirect option is set to 'manual' or 'error'.

Incredible - that was the issue. Removing the trailing slash returns results as expected. Is there a way to prevent this behavior - to prevent trailing slashes from causing a redirect?
